# Set Event picture with Graph API with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, events, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to figure this out all day...

With PHP SDK I can add a Facebook event to my Facebook page. But, if I try to set the wall picture of the events page, it isn't working. I found this:

```
/* make the API call */
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/{event-id}/picture",
    "POST",
    array (
        'source' => '{image-data}',
    )
);
/* handle the result */
```

But the image-data has to be in multipart/form-data format. Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, I found that you could do this with a 'url' parameter instead of the 'source' parameter, but this isn't working either.

Maybe I've missed some permissions in my app settings?

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking of the event page's cover photo. You've used the method described in the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/picture/#publish) to upload a cover photo of an event - **but** unfortunately this don't work as of now.

I've asked this before in the developers site, check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274455709396178/).

The **only** way to do this (as of now)-

`\POST /{event-id}` with param: `cover_url`

**Code:**

```
$param = array(
    'cover_url' => '{image-link}'
);

$facebook->api('/{event-id}', 'POST', $param);
```

(image data wont work, you require a link to image)